# Is there a good way to ask if you're being let go soon?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, management

So this could just be me being paranoid but I have this dreadful feeling that the company I'm working for is going to be letting me go soon.

They hired myself and another guy on at the same time, we're on 6 month contracts for them. We're a couple weeks away from the end of our probationary 3 month period, and I just can't help but feel that they're gearing up to let me go.

They've given the other new guy a key to the office already (he's usually one of the first people there in the morning so that was their reasoning for it). I still don't have a key yet though even though I've been told I'll be getting one (that was 2 weeks ago). Also, it just seems like they're giving this guy more work than they're giving me.

Like I said, it could just be me being paranoid since I was let go from my last job towards the end of the 6-month probation.

I really do like this job and everyone I work with, the last thing I want to have happen is to be let go.

Should I ask my supervisor if, for lack of a better way of putting it, if I should be looking for a new job? What is a good way of going about this, if any?

Comment: So turns out this is probably a non-issue. I got my key today after reminding one of the management about it, and I've started working on one of the larger projects we have on the go. This could be of help to someone else out there though, thanks for the answers!

Comment: You should start looking anyway. I don't mean invest tons of time, but it can't hurt to brush up your resume and put out a few feelers.

Comment: On an added note, it's now been almost 2 months since the end of my probation and I'm still with the company :)! Turned out to be a non-issue just as I said

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If I were in your shoes, I would have a conversation with my supervisor about the end of the probation period and ask for a review of the work so far.

Try to set the tone for the conversation as a milestone in your relationship with the organization where you want to learn more about yourself and how you can contribute even further. I would not ask for a conversation to see if you are a good fit for the role or not.

This conversation should have the two following outcomes:

1. Getting a feel if you are going to be let go or not.
2. Positioning yourself as an individual who want to get feedback on his job in order to get better at it.

Comment: +1  would have answered the same way, except that waiting further before asking for a review is pointless. I'd say, ask for feedback NOW on whether there is anything they'd like the OP to do so they're happy with the OP's work. Asking for feedback now is not going to change their evaluation of the work but it creates (hopefully) a perception that the OP does care, is responsive and dully diligent - a perception which might influence the decision whether to retain the OP's services. The OP can ask for a formal eview at the end of the probationary period.

Comment: Thank you! What does OP stand for?

Comment: @DavidSegonds : Original Poster (here Ryan J).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer David! While this might be a non-issue now (see my above comment in my question), I still may ask my supervisor about feedback to see what he can tell me. I'm always looking to improve!

Answer (score 10):

At every job I was, I had a weekly or monthly meetings with my superiors. I assume you have too. If not, ask him for a meeting to discuss how he sees your progress so far.

At the meeting you can mention all things that bothers you, but with positive tone. That means :

- do not ask "Are you going to let me go?" - instead "How do you see my progress so far? What can I do to improve further?". From answers to these questions, you should get an idea of whether they are going to keep you. But, 3 months may be too soon.
- regarding the key, just ask him directly. Maybe someone forgot. "I was wondering what happened with the key. I was told I'll get one."
- I would be very careful to ask for more, or more challenging, work. At least during probation.

Comment: monthly (or even weekly) performance meetings? I have never heard of that, for the companies I worked for the standard was maybe one or two in a year. I think each week would be strange for evaluation of your work, it is just way too short.

Comment: @dirkk: no, monthly or weekly one-to-ones with superiors, whose agenda allows for questions relating to performance as well as a lot of other possible agenda items. Normally the main focus of a one-to-one is what you're doing at the moment, but it needn't be restricted to that (depending on whatever rules the organisation has about them, as always).

Comment: @dirkk Steve is right. My performance meetings were and are once a year. Rest are normal meetings (what I do, my plans, any issues, etc)

Comment: Seems likely to have performance meetings more often than annually when (as OP states) you're in a 6 month contract with 3 month probationary period.